# Breaking links to external workbooks using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

What is the best way to break links to all external workbooks using Apache POI library? In our current interface, the formula evaluation is failing with below error when the formula refers to an external workbook:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not implemented yet
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getExternalSheetIndex(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.java:615)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:510)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426)
```

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html#external

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, will go through it.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, I used the FormulaEvaluator.setIgnoreMissingWorkbooks(true); and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Hello @AxelRichter, when the excel file cell has a reference to external workbook,the processing works fine when setIgnoreMissingWorkBooks(true) is set. However For Ex a cell A5 is =SUM(B1:B2) and both B1 and B2 are external workbook references , the processing fails with below error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid sheetIndex: -1.
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.<init>(SheetRefEvaluator.java:36)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:136)